# How can I run a function at the start of an iPhone Program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

so in my iPhone app at the start of the app I need to load a couple of external files, my problem is I want to load them as the app starts, but if I use viewDidLoad in objective c it'll first load my files and then display the screen. What can I do for the screen to appear first and then run all my functions?

Comment: can you please be a little more specific? Are you talking about the launch screen? or after the launch screen, show some images and then load your material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default.png always appears first; while it is showing you can start other tasks.

Can you do you file loads in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

You should not rely on your users being happy to stare at Default.png for long so the suggested process is to let it show, take a minimal amount of time to do whatever file operations you need to do - hopefully doing the heavy lifting in a background thread - then get some actual UI up and start the app as soon as possible.

If you are doing something with network (external files) you might get all the help you need from a library like AFNetworking which will let you kick off an operation and specify a block of code to be executed on receipt of the data, leaving you to get on with the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Run them in the background with something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // tasks
});
```

If the tasks don't *need* to run on the main queue, then running them on a separate queue is much better, since they won't block the user interface updates:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // tasks
});
```